# Make the enlarged digit vertically centered in normal text (digits almostly) height.

Tags: vertical-alignment, raise

I want a digit inside around other digits could centered vertically in height, without affecting by normal font size setting, as image show:

[image]

(The enlarged six is `{\Large6}`) but I couldn't get the result by using the `\raisebox` command and the `ex` length unit to raise. Please help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `\raisebox` is the right way. You can use `\height` to refer to the height of the content i.e. the height above the baseline. The `\depth` should be zero for normal numbers. You then need to subtract the `\height` from the  normal height and divide it by 2. The normal height from an uppercase letter is about 1.6ex or 80% of the `\strut` height given by `\ht\strutbox`. You can use e-TeX's `\dimexpr` to do the calculation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\vcentered}{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr.8\ht\strutbox-\height\relax}}

\begin{document}

0000\vcentered{\Large 6}00000\vcentered{\small 9}00000

0000\vcentered{\Huge 6}00000\vcentered{\tiny 9}00000

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

---

You could do it even more accurate if you would provide a reference for the normal height. In addition you could also take the depths in account.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\vrefbox}
\newcommand{\setvref}{\sbox{\vrefbox}}
\newcommand{\vcentered}{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\ht\vrefbox-\height\relax}}

\begin{document}

\setvref{0}0000\vcentered{\Large 6}00000\vcentered{\small 9}00000

\huge
\setvref{0}0000\vcentered{\Huge 6}00000\vcentered{\tiny 9}00000

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tikz` is redundancy?

Comment: @Leo: `tikz` would be overkill.

Comment: @Martin So why is it in the preamble? :-) (Which was Leo's question.)

Comment: @Alan: Ups. It's in my default preamble and I forgot to delete it in one of the code examples. Sorry, I didn't really understood what Leo meant.

Comment: @Stufazi Hoqckt: You are welcome. Please don't forget to accept and up-vote the correct answers to your questions. There are icons on the left side for that.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
\newcommand\vcentered[1]{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}}
```

instead of Martin's definition. Although it gets a little different *centered* text, it is originally designed for vertical alignment in TeX.

The key is *usage*:

```
\vcentered{00000}\vcentered{\Huge6}\vcentered{00000}%
\vcentered{\tiny 9}\vcentered{00000}
```

[image]

Comment: This gives my http://i.imgur.com/zfNA2.png. Especially the smaller 9 isn't correctly centered. AFAIK `\vcenter` centers to the baseline. The OP needs to have it centered towards the middle of the surrounding 0s.

Comment: @Martin: See the usage.

Comment: @Martin: `\vcenter` centers with respect to the *axis of formulas*; it's the imaginary line where the fraction lines are set.